# Trouble Inserting Data in SQLite Using long Always Returns -1

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm having trouble finding what's missing in my code. I'm trying to insert data but "*long result == db.insert*" in my DatabaseHelper class always returns -1". I cannot pin point what I'm doing wrong. Please help. Any Idea would be very appreciated.

My DatabaseHelper class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "drivefinal.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "drive_table";
public static final String ID = "ID";
public static final String NUMBER = "Number";
public static final String FNAME = "First Name";
public static final String LNAME = "Last Name";
public static final String COORDINATE = "Coordinate";
public static final String ADDRESS = "Address";
public static final String NOTES = "Notes";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists " + TABLE_NAME +"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,NUMBER TEXT,FNAME TEXT,LNAME TEXT,COORDINATE TEXT,ADDRESS TEXT,NOTES TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String number, String fName, String lName, String coordinate, String address, String notes){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(NUMBER, number);
    contentValues.put(FNAME, fName);
    contentValues.put(LNAME, lName);
    contentValues.put(COORDINATE, coordinate);
    contentValues.put(ADDRESS, address);
    contentValues.put(NOTES, notes);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
        if(result == -1 )
            return false;
        else
            return true;
}
```

My main activity file:

```
public void addData(){
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editTextnumber.getText().toString(),
                        editTextfname.getText().toString(),
                        editTextlname.getText().toString(),
                        editTextcoordinate.getText().toString(),
                        editTextaddress.getText().toString(),
                        editTextnotes.getText().toString());

                        if(isInserted)
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        );
}
```

}

Comment: Use `insertOrThrow()` rather than `insert()` for more descriptive error exceptions. You'll learn that your column names are not what you expect them to be.

Comment: @zoe Got it. Thank you

Comment: @laalto I'll try to implement that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table definition creates column names that are not the same as the column names you are trying to use when inserting.

e.g. your table will have the column name **FNAME** not **First Name** (etc).

Secondly you would have issues trying to use a column named **First Name** as it includes a space and would have to be enclosed e.g. **[First Name]**.

I'd suggest using :-

```
public static final String NUMBER = "Number";
public static final String FNAME = "FirstName"; //<<<<<<<<<< space removed
public static final String LNAME = "LastName"; //<<<<<<<<<< space removed
public static final String COORDINATE = "Coordinate";
public static final String ADDRESS = "Address";
public static final String NOTES = "Notes";
```

Along with :-

```
db.execSQL("create table if not exists " + TABLE_NAME +"(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," + NUMBER + " TEXT," + FNAME + " TEXT," + LNAME + " TEXT," + COORDINATE + " TEXT," + ADDRESS + " TEXT," + NOTES + " TEXT)");
```

To introduce the changes (i.e. for the onCreate method to run, as it only runs automatically when creating the database) you would have to do one of the following :-

- Delete the App's data.
- Uninstall the App.
- Change the database version number e.g. change `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);` to `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);`

and then rerun the App.

Comment: I appreciate the "To introduce the changes" as well.